# How do I decode this JSON payload (msearch esasticsearch)?

Tags: javascript, python, json, reverse-engineering

**I am trying to reverse engineer an API call to this url: https://respublica.co/elasticsearch/msearch**

When I look in the payload tab, the JSON query looks like this and I do not understand it, is ther anyway I could decode this?

```
{"z":"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","y":"bM0kriQGnK34eBZ6Cz30sA==","x":"a7bsy6/TdR2roPynoJBNxLE9Pn86gf2KxVh+6nOXRdE="}
```

I can send a request with this payload, but I want to alter it so I can lookup different users on the API

This is the URL of the website that makes the request: https://respublica.co/profile?user=Cao_Cao

Comment: Looks like base64. There are plenty of online base64 decoders and both javascript and python have functions for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, when I tried decoding it with a base64 decoder, it just looked like jumbled up ascii characters, what does this mean?

Comment: Since base64 decoding looks like it fails, my next assumption is it is some sort of DES encoded string result. Without the secret key, you probably cannot decode it properly to a standard string.